# sudo: unable to resolve host "hostname"

Tags: sudo, hostname, vps

I'm testing a VPS provider, and recently created a virtual machine with a hostname `testserver` using an ubuntu template. This VPS provider reserves and bills resources by the month, so if you create a VM for a small job, it's sensible to keep it around in case you need another VM for some other job later.

I came back to VM after a couple of weeks for another job, and wanted to rename the hostname to `webserver`. I edited `/etc/hostname` and rebooted, and the OS recognises that the hostname is now `webserver`. According to the VPS vendor, it's apparently impossible to change the hostname of the VM in the hypervisor resource group (read they haven't created a controller view and form template to do so), so I'm stuck with it being called `testserver` there. `sudo` works, but when I `sudo` I get a warning:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host webserver
```

Anyone know why? This is obviously just a minor inconvenience, but I thought I would ask in case anyone knows of a solution.

Comment: does your resolver (`grep hosts: /etc/nsswitch.conf`) include 'files'? If so, an entry in /etc/hosts should do it.

Comment: Yep, that was it; the original hostname was there next to the IP instead. Thanks! Paste as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sudo uses the system resolver, configured by `/etc/nsswitch.conf`; in your case, host lookups were configured to use `/etc/hosts`, which had the previous hostname identified with the server's IP. To fix it, simply update /etc/hosts with the new hostname.

Comment: You'll also want to look at (for example) /etc/hostname and any other network configuration files (/etc/sysconfig/network on RHEL) for places that had the old hostname.